# Calculate state recursively using map/reduce?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects, let's say

```
let objs: foo[];
```

an immutable state object

```
let state: State;
```

and a function

```
transform: (state: State, obj: foo) => State;
```

So `transform` calculates a new `State` from the previous one using the information from the current `obj`; if you're thinking 'sounds like Redux to me' you could be right.

Is there a way to call `transform` recursively for each object from the array such, that each calculated `state` is the input parameter for the next call to `transform` using `map` and `reduce`? I'm only interested in the final `state`.

I tried something like

```
let finalState = objs.reduce((prev: State, curr: foo) => transform(prev, curr), state)
```

but as `reduce` requires `prev`and `curr` to be of type `foo` (the array type) this is not going to work obviously.

Comment: Have you tried `objs.foreach(x=>this.transform(state, x))`?

Comment: It does sound like `reduce` is what you're looking for, except for the *recursive* part. You're saying your objects have some property themselves that is an array (?) you want to recursively `reduce` over? You're asking for a recursive `reduce` implementation?

Comment: I might be missing something but I don't see why is recursion involved

Comment: Think of this as `state[i+1] = transform(state[i], objs[i])` where each `state` is immutable. Given an array of `objs: foo[n]` I need `state[n]`. This is very similar to aggregating stuff, that's why my hunch is this could work using `reduce`.

Comment: Yes indeed. From the way you talk, it does sound like you should be familiar with how `reduce` works and how to apply it. What exactly is your concern/question? Have you tried applying `reduce` and come across some specific stumbling block?

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the current `index` provided by `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
return objs.reduce((prev, next, index) => transform(prev, objs[index]), state);
```

But this way you're kind off abusing the `reduce` function. Imo this should and could be done with a regular `forEach` statement:

```
function getFinalState(state: State, objs: Obj[]) : State {
    objs.forEach(x => state = transform(state, x));

    return state;
}
```

See this [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%09text%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Obj%20%7B%0D%0A%09description%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20state%3A%20State%20%3D%20%7B%20text%3A%20'init'%20%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20objs%3A%20Obj%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%09%7B%20description%3A%20'a'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%09%7B%20description%3A%20'b'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%09%7B%20description%3A%20'c'%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20transform(state%3A%20State%2C%20obj%3A%20Obj)%20%3A%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09text%3A%20obj.description%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getFinalState(state%3A%20State%2C%20objs%3A%20Obj%5B%5D)%20%3A%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%09objs.forEach(x%20%3D%3E%20state%20%3D%20transform(state%2C%20x))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09return%20state%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getFinalStateReduce(state%3A%20State%2C%20objs%3A%20Obj%5B%5D)%3A%20State%7B%0D%0A%09return%20objs.reduce((prev%2C%20next%2C%20index)%20%3D%3E%20transform(prev%2C%20objs%5Bindex%5D)%2C%20state)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20final%20%3D%20getFinalStateReduce(state%2C%20objs)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(final)%3B) for working samples